# Can I add error messages to Expectation tests in RhinoMocks?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

When doing an `Assert` call you have method overloads which take a message e.g. `Assert.AreEqual(x,y,"x should equal y");`

Is there a way to do this when setting expectations on mock objects e.g. the `Expect(...)` methods?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've just looked at the decompiled code for `Expect` in  `Rhino Mocks v3.6.1`, which is the latest on NuGet, and none of the overloads allows a string message to be passed.

Comment: The following blog post seems to be the closest thing to what (I think) you're looking for: http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2009/09/09/rhino-mocks-meaningful-failure-messages-on-expectations.aspx